# React Semantic-UI Dropdown item with bold and underline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to set a React-Semantic-UI dropdown title in bold and underline using this

```
<Dropdown text={<strong><ins>About</ins></strong>} simple item style={{ lineHeight: '0' }} >
```

which works (so no problem with the styling).
But the console returns this warning

> Warning: Failed prop react-refresh-runtime.development.js:39 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `text` of type `object` supplied to `Dropdown`, expected `string`.

How should I set the formatting such as the warning is fixed?